# Get File info before uploading using javascript cross browser solution

Tags: javascript, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, fileapi

I know File API of HTML5 is not supported in any version of IE.But is there any work around to get file information (size,type) before uploading it to server using javascript.
I need to check size of file before uploading it.
File Api does the work for me, but not for IE. I need it to support for IE as well

Comment: Only File API can get the file information from file input elements. There's no other way except via plugin, if a web browser doesn't support it yet, really.

Answer (score 1):

In pure JS it is not possible.

Javascript does not have access to local files, due security reasons.

You can use this library, to do what you want: http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/